# Making $\frac{z_3 - z_1}{z_2 - z_1} \cdot \frac{z - z_2}{z - z_3}$ a real number

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z_1 = 18 + 83i$, $z_2 = 18 + 39i,$ and $z_3 = 78 + 99i.$ Let $z$ be the unique complex number with the properties that $$\frac{z_3 - z_1}{z_2 - z_1} \cdot \frac{z - z_2}{z - z_3}$$ is a real number and the imaginary part of $z$ is the greatest possible. Find the real part of $z$.

---

I substituted in given values which gave me $$\frac{78 + 99i - (18 + 83i)}{18 + 39i - (18 + 83i)} \cdot \frac{z - (18 + 39i)}{z - (78 + 99i)} =\frac{-4 + 5i}{11} \cdot \frac{(a-18) + (b - 39)i}{(a-78) + (b - 99)i} c + 0 \cdot i.$$ However, I'm not sure how to move on from here. Can someone give a hint as to a cleaner way to do this, or if I just have to bash this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{z_3 - z_1}{z_2 - z_1} \cdot \frac{z - z_2}{z - z_3} = (z, z_1, z_2, z_3)
$$
is the [cross-ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio) of $z, z_1, z_2, z_3$. It is real if and only if the four numbers lie on a circle (or line).

So it suffices to determine the circle through $z_1, z_2, z_3$ and then determine the point with largest imaginary part on that circle.